# Flutter http get request button. Don't need response

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm looking for a simple flutter example of an elevated button with (onPressed) http request opening hardcoded url. I don't need response. I don't need browser window to appear. Target OS is Android. Thanks in advance.
UPD: i don't need any output. Just need to open urls such as https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=SECRET_KEY&message=test to trigger tasker (android app) tasks..

SOLUTION:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
The button:
Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(child: const Text('Flashlight on'), onPressed: () {const url = 'https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=SECRET_KEY&message=flashlight%20on';_launchHTTP(url);},),)

The function:    
void _launchHTTP(String url) async {
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
}
```

Comment: please share your code with what you are trying and what is expected output you want.

Comment: for http request in flutter checkout this official link- https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook#networking

Comment: i was using "import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';" to open tasker urls such as "tasker://assistantactions?task=task_name" It works  . But it opens a browser window if i open http url . I should be using "import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;"
now...

Comment: above url_launcher use for open dailpad, open apps from our apps or webview to load url. please update you question with your code with expected  output too.

Comment: I don't have http code yet. I only find examples expecting response with "Future". I only need to open an url in background

Comment: Check [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/http).

Comment: Yeah. There are some simple examples on the "http package"'s page. Thanks

Comment: What you need is a server-based callback technique. This cannot be done on the client side.

Comment: I've updated the question with the working solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
The button:
Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(child: const Text('Flashlight on'), onPressed: () {const url = 'https://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=SECRET_KEY&message=flashlight%20on';_launchHTTP(url);},),)

The function:    
void _launchHTTP(String url) async {
await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
}
```